# How to connect to Ubuntu using Serial Port?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, pipe, serial-port

I am using VMware and I want to connect to Ubuntu VMs via serial port. I am connecting both using pipe as referred in this website https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_devices3.html
How do I proceed to connecting and using them?

Comment: The link you provided seems to describe various ways of connecting a serial port in the VM to real ports on the host side.  How is that incomplete?  Exactly *what* are you connecting to the serial ports on each end?  Or are you trying to setup the console on the serial port?

Comment: @sawdust Yes, I'm trying to setup the console on serial port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably try this in three steps:
1. setup a *terminal emulator* program on the Host side.
2. test the login program on the VM side.
3. setup Ubuntu to boot with a serial console.

Step #2 will verify that you have a working virtual serial link before attempting the more complex step #3.  Otherwise step #2 is just a test, and not a required step in setting up a serial console.  The first half of step #3 may suffice for your requirements (which you have not described) and then you won't have to do any boot parameter modifications.

**Step 1:**  setup a *terminal emulator* program on the Host side.

Follow the VMware guide that you mention for "Connecting an Application on the Host to a Virtual Machine".  The "application on the Host" will be a *terminal emulator* program such a HyperTerminal, Putty or TeraTerm (the later two are preferred and multi-platform).  You are going to use only the bare essentials of the *terminal emulator* program; you do not need any SSH or telnet or even modem capability.

Configure the Host's *terminal emulator* for VT102 emulation and the port to 115200 baud, 8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit.  Use the lowest numbered serial port (e.g. COM1 or ttyS0) from VMware.

**Step 2:**  test the login program on the VM (Ubuntu) side.

Use the lowest numbered serial port, /dev/ttyS0.
Make sure your username is a member of group "dialout" (which should own /dev/ttyS0).

Configure the virtual serial port at the Ubuntu shell prompt:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyS0 cs8 -parenb -cstopb 115200
$ echo Hello world >/dev/ttyS0
```

Inspect the *terminal emulator* program for output.

Execute the login program for the serial connection.

```
$ sudo getty -8L 115200 ttyS0 VT102
```

Try to login at the *terminal emulator* program.

**Step 3:** setup Ubuntu to boot with a serial console.

If you get this far, then you should use the [Ubuntu howto for serial console](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto).

The "Configuring the console login process" will use the same *getty* that was tested in the previous step.  This configuration is to ensure that *getty* is re-executed (or "respawned") at the appropriate runlevels and after each logoff.  Note that there are different startup procedures depending on the version of Ubuntu, so I won't bother trying to reiterate that here.

Configuring `grub`(or whatever virtual bootloader) might be optional for you.  At this point you would have a setup that provides the serial port as a user login terminal.  If you proceed to make changes to the boot parameters for the kernel command line, then all you will get is make visible the kernel output during boot.